# Как отпавить дополнительные параметры dropezone.js?

Tags: javascript

[Вот станица самого плагина](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) проблема в том что запросом отправляется только картинка, а появилась необходимость отправлять дополнительные параметры,  адрес по которому будет сохранятся картинка  который хранится в переменой imagPath Это возможно реализовать ?

Comment: Вы собираетесь сохранять картинки в разные папки на сервере?

Comment: @Александр да хочу

Comment: @Александр Отдельно для условно говоря постов, категорий, страниц, товаров и т.д. . И не спрашивайте почему мне это не возможно сделать на сервере если бы мог я бы это сделал. Там форма создается через ajax.  По ссылке которая сама создана скриптом

Comment: Тогда я не понимаю, как Вы хотите сохранять картинки в разные папки на сервере, если к нему доступа не имеете. Передать дополнительные данные Вы сможете, а вот как их обработать на стороне сервера? Или такой функционал уже на стороне сервера заложен?

Comment: @Александр для того что бы обработать мне нужно передать дополнительным параметром imagePath где заложена одна часть пути которая потом добавляется к другой прописанной на сервере и мы получаем одну строку являющейся полным путем для сохранения картинки. Условно есть массив в confige там прописывается часть пути которую я получаю в представлении и передаю дальше на обработчик, Вот мне надо передать эту часть.